# Equivalence of Subspace and Finite Complement Topologies on a Subset

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

> Let $X$ be a set and $\left(X, \mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{f}}\right)$ be the topological space with the finite complement topology $\mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{f}}$.
> Show: For any subset $Y \subseteq X$, the subspace topology on $Y$ inherited from $\left(X, \mathcal{T}_{\mathrm{f}}\right)$ is the same as the finite complement topology on $Y$.

Utilizing the given definitions of the subspace topology and the finite complement topology, we know that a topological space $\left(X, \mathcal{T}_f\right)$ with the finite complement topology $\mathcal{T}_f$, where a subset $U$ of $X$ is open if $X-U$ is finite or if $U=\varnothing$. The subspace topology $\mathcal{T}_Y$ on $Y$, inherited from $\left(X, \mathcal{T}_f\right)$, is defined as $\mathcal{T}_Y=\left\{Y \cap U \mid U \in \mathcal{T}_f\right\}$.

Now, by the definition of subspace and finite complement topologies:

- $\mathcal{T}_f$, the finite complement topology on $X$, is defined as:
  $$
  \mathcal{T}_f=\{U \subseteq X \mid U=\varnothing \text { or } X-U \text { is a finite set }\}
  $$
- $\mathcal{T}_Y$, the subspace topology on $Y$, is defined as:
  $$
  \mathcal{T}_Y=\left\{Y \cap U \mid U \in \mathcal{T}_f\right\}
  $$
- $\mathcal{T}_f^Y$, the finite complement topology directly defined on $Y$, is defined as:
  $$
  \mathcal{T}_f^Y=\{V \subseteq Y \mid V=\varnothing \text { or } Y-V \text { is a finite set }\}
  $$

To prove: $\mathcal{T}_f^Y=\mathcal{T}_Y$ by first proving $\mathcal{T}_Y \subseteq \mathcal{T}_f^Y$ and then $\mathcal{T}_f^Y \subseteq \mathcal{T}_Y$.

**1. $\mathcal{T}_Y \subseteq \mathcal{T}_f^Y$**

- Consider an arbitrary set $W \in \mathcal{T}_Y$. Then there exists a $U \in \mathcal{T}_f$ such that $W=Y \cap U$.
- Since $U \in \mathcal{T}_f$, we have two possibilities for $U$ :

1.1. $U=\varnothing$, which implies $W=Y \cap \varnothing=\varnothing$, and $\varnothing$ is obviously open in any topology, including $\mathcal{T}_f^Y$.

1.2. $U \neq \varnothing$, and hence $X-U$ is finite since $U$ is open in $\mathcal{T}_f$. This means that the complement of $U$ in $X$ is finite.

- If $U \neq \varnothing$, consider the complement of $W$ in $Y$, given by $Y-W=Y \backslash(Y \cap U)=$ ?

I don't know how to continue the proof.

**2. $\mathcal{T}_f^Y \subseteq \mathcal{T}_Y$ :**

- Take an arbitrary set $V \in \mathcal{T}_f^Y$. Then $V=\emptyset$ or $Y-V$ is finite, since $V$ is open in the finite complement topology on $Y$.\

1.1. If $V=\emptyset$, then $V \in \mathcal{T}_Y$ since $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is a topology.

1.2. If $Y-V$ is finite.

I also don't know how to go further here. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: For your first point: What is the inclusion relation between the sets $Y\setminus (Y\cap U)=Y\setminus U$ and $X\setminus (X\cap U)=X\setminus U$?

Comment: For your second question: consider $Y\setminus V=X\setminus (X\setminus (Y\setminus V))$

Comment: $Y \backslash (Y \cap U)$ is the set of elements that are in $Y$ but not in the intersection of $Y$ and $U$. This is the set of all elements that are in $Y$ but not in $U$. $Y \backslash U$ is the set of elements that are in $Y$ but not in $U$. But since $U$ might include elements not in $Y$, this expression directly excludes elements from $U$ that are in $Y$. Is it like this ? @watertrainer I don't see how it relates to the proof yet?

Comment: Your description of the topology is slightly wrong (probably a momentary lapse): A set $U$ is open if and only if $X\setminus U$ is finite or $U=\varnothing$ (not "$U=X$").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.

Below, I use "$-$" to denote the set-theoretic difference. We will also assume that $U \ne \emptyset$. If it is the case that $U 
= \emptyset$, it is trivially open in any topology.

($\mathcal{T}_Y \subseteq \mathcal{T}_f^Y$) Let $U \in \mathcal{T}_Y$. Then by definition, there exists $V \in \mathcal{T}_f^X$ such that $U = V \cap Y$. To show that $U \in \mathcal{T}_f^Y$, we need to show that $Y - U$ is finite. Consider the fact that

$$Y - U = Y \cap (X - U) = Y \cap (X - V \cap Y) \subseteq X - V \cap Y \subseteq X - V$$

Since $X - V$ is finite by hypothesis, $Y - U$ must be finite, as desired.

($\mathcal{T}_f^Y \subseteq \mathcal{T}_Y$) Let $U \in \mathcal{T}_f^Y$; we would like to show that $U \in \mathcal{T}_Y$. To do so, we can find $V \in \mathcal{T}_f^X$ such that $U = Y \cap V$. Consider $V = (X - Y) \cup U$. It is easy to check that $V$ is open in $X$, since

$$X - V = X - ((X - Y) \cup U) = (X - (X - Y)) \cap (X - U) = Y \cap (X - U) = Y - U$$

which is finite by hypothesis. And it is easy to check that

$$Y \cap V = (Y \cap (X - Y)) \cup (Y \cap U) = \emptyset \cup (Y \cap U) = Y \cap U = U$$

Comment: Thnx! The only thing I don't understand yet is why $Y-U=Y \cap(X-U)$ and $X-((X-Y) \cup U)=(X-(X-Y)) \cap(X-U)=Y \cap(X-U)=Y-U$? I find it hard to understand and come up with these equations regarding complements, do you have any tips for this?

Comment: No problem. $Y - U$ can be thought of as $Y \cap (X - U)$, the elements that are in $Y$ but not in $U$ (treating $X$ as the universal set). Similarly, $X - ((X - Y) \cup U)$ can be described as the set of elements that are not in $U$ nor the complement of $Y$. These elements must therefore be contained in both $Y$ and $X - U$, by deMorgan's Law. That is, these elements are contained in $Y$ but not $U$ (again, $X$ is the universal set).